# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support web push on Mac safari(16.1)?

Tags: macos, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am wondering if fcm support web push on Mac Safari(16.1), because it is said that mac safari over 16.1 has already supported push API.

I have updated my safari to the latest version 16.1 on Mac and try to test web push using fcm, but it still doesn't work.

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`